# Arquitetura de entidades em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entidade-relacionamento

Estou com dúvida sobre como seria a melhor maneira de representar uma entidade de nome cliente que pode possuir sub-camadas da mesma entidade.

Cliente pode possuir outro Cliente que na verdade é uma transportadora, e essa Transpostadora pode possuir outro Cliente que é um corretor.

Pensei em criar classes extendidas `Cliente < Transportador < Corretor`, já que todas possuem basicamente os mesmo atributos.

Já fiz muito isso em Java mas um amigo rubista, certa vez me disse que detestava esse tipo de prática.

Abaixo segue a estrutura e o diagrama de classes que pensei em criar. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de estudar o guia http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
Resolvi o problema utilizado o self join. Agora consegui mapear os Clientes de um corretor e os Corretores de uma Seguradora.